# Do Any "Geometrical Inscription Theorems" Exist?

Tags: geometry

**Are there any general classes of mathematical theorems that describe the geometry of inscribed figures?**

For instance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_figure):

[image]

I am interested in theorems and the origins of the theorems that proved **"given a shape of certain dimension (e.g. a square with area measuring 1 unit squared) - what is the biggest area of another shape (e.g. circle, triangle, etc.) that can be inscribed into that shape?"** (i.e. what is the biggest percent of the larger shape will be left empty?)

I tried to read more about this stuff (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) and came across this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle) :

**Note 1 :** " In geometry, the incircle or inscribed circle of a triangle is the largest circle contained in the triangle; it touches (is tangent to) the three sides. The center of the incircle is a triangle center called the triangle's incenter. "

[image]

**Note 2:** I also came across this link here that (I think) states the same result but in simpler terms: https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-interactive-geometry-for-ccss/section/8.5/primary/lesson/inscribed-and-circumscribed-circles-of-triangles-geo-ccss/

[image]

**My Questions:**

**1)** **In the case of the largest "inscribed circle in a triangle", do we know who first proved this?** I am guessing it was probably Euclid (since Euclid proved a lot of similar results). I found this link here that states Euclid first proved this result in "Proposition 4" ([https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIV/propIV4.html](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIV/propIV4.html)) - but no where in "Proposition 4" is it mentioned that the inscribed circle in this triangle is also the biggest circle that can be inscribed? (**I am guessing that in most cases, a circle will likely be the largest type of shape that can be inscribed into almost any other shape - is this generally correct?**)

**2)** The above example only covers the case of the inscribed circle within the triangle - **but are there any theorems that make general claims for n-sided polygons inscribed in m-sided polygons (where m>n)** ? For instance, what is the biggest pentagon that can be inscribed into a octagon? What is the biggest circle that can fit into a hexagon? If no such theorems exist for general inscriptions - I would still be interested in learning about theorems that describe particular inscription instances (e.g. maybe a theorem exists that describes the biggest triangle that can be fit into a circle).

Thanks!

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of those formulas for [regular polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon).

Comment: @ dvix: thank you for this link! i am a bit confused - no where in this wikipedia link does it mention the "limits of inscription"? thank you so much!

Comment: Back when I posted my comment, the question was about regular polygons, and the link gives the relation between the circumradius and inradius (apothem) which is relevant to the largest inscribed circle part.

Answer (score 2):

First, it should be intuitively obvious that there is a largest such shape that fits inside any other shape. More rigorously, if you can parametrize any such shape (i.e. by the center and radius of the circle or the location of the vertices of a polygon), then this space is bounded and closed, so it’s compact and so any continuous function (like area) obtains it’s maximum for some shape.

Second, you can ask about what properties the largest shape must have. When inscribing in a triangle, if it weren’t touching all three sides, then you could scale everything up slightly from the opposite vertex giving a larger circle, contradicting it’s maximality. Thus, the largest such circle must touch all three sides. You can then notice that the center is the intersection of the angle bisectors and so is unique.

For general polygons, it’s not always possible to have a circle touch all the sides. One such counterexample is a long skinny rectangle. However, there always is a maximal circle that touches 3 such sides. For regular polygons, the circle will be centered at the center point, and tangent to all the sides.

The largest shape you can stick into any given shape is itself. The circle does have the nice property of having the highest area for a given perimeter.

For a triangle inside of a convex polygon, by a similar maximality argument, the vertices may be a subset of the outer polygons vertices, otherwise you could increase the area by moving the vertices torwards or along the edges. A similar argument applies to any polygon inside of a convex polygon. For regular polygons, you want to spread the vertices out as much as possible, so for example a maximal triangle inside of a 10 sides regular polygon would be the outer vertices separated by 3,4,4 edges.

For a pentagon inside a convex octagon, you’d just need to try all subsets of 5 of the 8 vertices. If it’s a regular octagon, you’d just choose vertices that are 1,1,2,2,2 outer edges apart from each other. The order doesn’t matter.